# Python C++ api - return different types in function overloading

Tags: python, c++, overloading, python-c-api

I have a C++ class that contains two overloaded methods **sayHi()**, each with a different return type:

```
class Box {
   public:

      Box();

      void sayHi(char *name);

      int sayHi(int number);

};
```

When I tried to wrap this functions, I followed the suggestion by [ShadowRanger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56042357/python-c-api-function-overloading) and 
**"write a single wrapper function that type checks the argument provided and dispatches to the correct 'real' function"**.

Here it is:

```
static PyObject *pyBox_sayHi_char(PyBox *self, char *Name)
{
    self->bx->sayHi(Name);

    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

static int *pyBox_sayHi_int(PyBox *self,  int number)
{
    int answer;

    answer = self->bx->sayHi(number);

    return answer;
}

static PyObject *Hi_overload_switch(PyBox *self,  PyObject *args)
{
    PyObject *x;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &x))
        return NULL;

    if (PyUnicode_Check(x))
    {
        const char* s = PyBytes_AsString(PyUnicode_AsUTF8String(x)); // convert PyObject to char*

        Py_DECREF(x);

        return pyBox_sayHi_char(self, s);
    }
    if (PyLong_Check(x))
    {   
        return pyBox_sayHi_int( self, PyLong_AsLong(x) );
    }
    Py_RETURN_NOTIMPLEMENTED;
}
```

and the following methods table:

```
static PyMethodDef pyBox_methods[] = {
    {"Hi", (PyCFunction)Hi_overload_switch, METH_VARARGS, "Hi"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};
```

However, I am getting the error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘PyObject*’ {aka ‘_object*’} in return
         return pyBox_sayHi_int( self, PyLong_AsLong(x) );
```

AFAIK, I don't want to convert the return types into PyObjects, since the overloaded methods might need to return custom types. Therefore the **int** vs **void** in my example is just for illustration purposes - I might well have written **PyBanana** vs **PyOrange** data types.

My question is, how do I make the function **Hi_overload_switch** return different types?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a Python `int`. In C/C++ source this is a [`PyLongObject`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html) (Which is a subtype of `PyObject`, so you can cast a `PyLongObject*` to a `PyObject*` and back). To convert a C++ `int` into a `PyObject*` Python `int`, use [`PyObject* PyLong_FromLong(long)`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_FromLong):

```
static PyObject *pyBox_sayHi_int(PyBox *self,  int number)
{
    int answer;

    answer = self->bx->sayHi(number);

    return PyLong_FromLong(answer);
}
```